WSL brew update error - cannot load file fiddle
I just installed Homebrew on my linux subsystem and it wouldn't allow me to update it. Any idea why this might have happened? Homebrew version is 4.3.22 now, but i want to be able to solve this for the future and not having to uninstall and reinstall everytime.
==> Updating Homebrew...
Error: cannot load such file -- fiddle
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/linkage_checker.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/descriptions.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/update-report.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
<internal:/home/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/extend/kernel.rb:11:in `require?'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/commands.rb:37:in `valid_internal_cmd?'
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:65:in `<main>'


Try sudo apt-get install libffi-dev and then gem install fiddle

@engineersmnky can you tell me more about what you're suggesting me to install? what does libffi-dev do?
